# Searching for NA in a list of lists

Tags: r, list, na

Is it possible to locate NAs (missing values) and return their location with both list and column?

Please consider this data:

```
list1 <- list(a = c(1, 2), b = c(3, 4), c = c(5, NA))
list2 <- list(d = c(6, 7), e = c(8, 9), f = c("a", "b"))
mylist <- mget(c("list1", "list2"))
```

The expected return would be something like `list1$c`.

I tried to use `rlist` with the function `list.search`. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Maybe `rapply(mylist, anyNA)` but the `names` of the output are not in the format `list1$c`.

Comment: That's a good solution, which indicates the list where NA is present. Thanks for it, it's very helpful! I am going to wait for a full solution.

Comment: Your `mylist` does not contain the names of *list1* and *list2*, so the solution form @RuiBarradas can not return those names. So try the following: `mylist <- mget(c("list1", "list2"))` and then `gsub("\\.", "$", names(which(rapply(mylist, anyNA))))`

Comment: This works really well, @GKi!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pretty straightforward approach would be using `rapply` with `is.na()`. Something like this would be close to your desired result:

```
> rapply(mylist, is.na)
   a1    a2    b1    b2    c1    c2    d1    d2    e1    e2    f1    f2 
FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE 

> which(rapply(mylist, is.na))
c2 
 6
```

Comment: Could you please modify your answer to take into account @GKi's comments? Therefore, I could accept/confirm your answer. Thanks